# My 'IF' statent doesn't do what I've it expected to do

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm trying to have user input where user types a letter and then depends on letter 'IF' statement chooses which fields to display.

What I have now if I type 'p' and 'P' or 'F' or 'f' my 'for' statement still don't understand my input and throws me to 'else' statement.

But why not?

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Employee's Last Name: ");
        inputName = scanner.next();
        System.out.print("Employment Status (F or P): ");
        inputStatus = scanner.next();

        if (inputStatus == "F" || inputStatus == "f")
        {
            // some code
        }
        else if(inputStatus == "P" || inputStatus == "p")
        {
            // some code
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("I don't understand...");
        }
```

Comment: `.equalsIgnoreCase("F")`

Comment: Not sure, but a good start would be: System.out.println("I don't understand..."); --> System.out.println("I don't understand, I got: " + inputStatus);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Always use equals for string Comparison. & equalsIgnoreCase for case independent comparision
>
> Also if one of the parameter is fixed string it should be used to compare like in your case `F` which avoid unnecessary null checks.

```
"F".equalsIgnoreCase(inputStatus)
```

Your code should look something like below.

```
   System.out.print("Employee's Last Name: ");
    String inputName = null;
    String inputStatus = null;
    if (scanner.hasNext())
        inputName = scanner.next();
    System.out.print("Employment Status (F or P): ");
    if (scanner.hasNext())
        inputStatus = scanner.next();

    if ("F".equalsIgnoreCase(inputStatus)) {
        // some code
    } else if ("P".equalsIgnoreCase(inputStatus)) {
        // some code
    } else {
        System.out.println("I don't understand...");
    }
```

Comment: +1 for using `equalsIgnoreCase` with literal string and not object. This avoids `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use equalsIgnoreCase() method.

```
if (inputStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("f"))
            {
                // some code
                System.out.println(inputStatus);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the strings `equals()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare strings using `==` operator. This operator compares references. Use `equals()` method instead:

`if ("F".equals(inputStatus) || "f".equals(inputStatus))`

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare `Strings` if "==", this basically compares the memory address of the two values, which will never match.

You should use something like...

```
if (inputStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("f")) 
{
    // Do something...
}
```

instead